# Odata Error - Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load (SAP)

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to consume an ODATA service with my UI5 App. I have created a simple table and the ODATA services in the ERP backend. When I am testing the services it is working fine, I can see the metadata and also the JSON. However when I am running my app( Web Preview ) it gives me following error.

**Uncaught (in promise) Object
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**.
"Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load **"'https://Username:password"ERP System info":"port"/sap/opu/odata/sap/"my Odata service name"/$metadata'"**

When I run my application on ABAP server it works fine.
Here is the code for ODATA in the controller.

var sServiceUrl = "https://"ERP System info":"port"/sap/opu/odata/sap/"my Odata service name"/";

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, false,
         "Username", "Password");

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Issue solved by adding the proxy in web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of proxy....just change the service URL to:

```
var sServiceUrl = "proxy/https/"ERP System info":"port"/sap/opu/odata/sap/"my Odata service name"/";
```